# Python/pcolormesh:TypeError: Dimensions of C (24, 4) are incompatible with X (24) and/or Y (24)

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'am getting this error(TypeError: Dimensions of C (24, 4) are incompatible with X (24) and/or Y (24); see help(pcolor)),at the line for pcolormesh, any idea how to handle this.

Script:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data = np.loadtxt('out (copie).txt')
lats = data[:,0].astype(int)
lons = data[:,1].astype(int)
codg_tec = data[:,2].astype(int)

m = Basemap(projection = 'merc', llcrnrlon= -9, llcrnrlat=19, urcrnrlon= 12, urcrnrlat= 37,  resolution= 'i')
m.drawcoastlines()

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = m(lon, lat)

cb = m.pcolormesh(x, y, np.squeeze(data[codg_tec]) , shading='flat', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
cbar = m.colorbar(cb, location = 'right', pad = '10%')

m.drawmapboundary()
m.drawmapscale()
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-9,12,5), labels=[False,False,False,True])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(19,38,5), labels=[True,False,False,False])
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()

plt.title('CODG-vTEC on 02-01-2015')
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "color.py", line 22, in <module>
    cb = m.pcolor(x, y, data[codg_tec] , shading='flat', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
  File "/home/bachi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 547, in with_transform
    return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/home/bachi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 3392, in pcolor
    ret = ax.pcolor(x,y,data,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1718, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5372, in pcolor
X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolor', *args, allmatch=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5216, in _pcolorargs
C.shape, Nx, Ny, funcname))
TypeError: Dimensions of C (24, 4) are incompatible with X (24) and/or Y (24); see help(pcolor)
```